# Multiple errors with Radio Group in android

Tags: android, xml, radio-group

Im getting errors such as :
Error passing XML: unbound prefix
attribute missing android namespace prefix
ive triad adding : xmlns:android but it wouldnt recognize it
Code:

```
<RadioGroup 

andorid:orientation = "vertical"
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
andorid:layout_weight = "1"
>


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: You cannot set the same id to every button, use different id´s

Comment: Just do something else for about 10 minutes then look at the file again (hint: spelling)

Comment: @MichaelButscher
thanks so much i have been staring at this code for 20 mins and i finally got it

Answer (score 0):

first of all, You have to set different Ids to Your buttons:

```
    <RadioGroup 

 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 >


<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

and second...is this the whole xml? You have to set

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the beginning and

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to the radio group

Comment: ill comment a link in a second

Answer (score 0):

If you change the RadioButtons Id, It works!.
=D

Answer (score 0):

```
I expect below code works 100%
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>
```

You can use android:weightSum="" instead of android:layout_weight="" .